# Dynamic beginning of for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, conditional-statements

Create bash for loop with two alternative starts. I would like to either iterate through all numbers in a range or all elements in an array depending on a condition. The following unorthodox code shows the example:

```
#!/bin/bash
FROMVAL=1
TOVAL=5
VALARR=(1 3 5)
ISCONSEQ=1
if (( ISCONSEQ == 1 )); then
        for (( counter=$FROMVAL; counter<=$TOVAL; counter++ ))
else
        for counter in "${VALARR[@]}"
fi
        do
                echo $counter
        done
```

Obviously, this does not work nor is it pretty. Is there a bash way to do this or should I create two for loops and execute only one depending on the content of `ISCONSEQ`? Or should I use a `for...in` loop for both cases and simply assign the values of my sequence to the array?

This code does work but relies only on the array:

```
if (( ISCONSEQ == 1 )); then
        VALARR=($(seq $FROMVAL 1 $TOVAL))
fi
for counter in "${VALARR[@]}"
do
        echo $counter
done
```

Comment: yes - just have two for loops. Simple.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for a function.   Create function for the echo and call it from each for loop.   It would look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
FROMVAL=1
TOVAL=5
VALARR=(1 3 5)
ISCONSEQ=1

function dostuff() {
   echo $*
}

if (( ISCONSEQ == 1 )); then
        for (( counter=$FROMVAL; counter<=$TOVAL; counter++ ))
        do
            dostuff $counter
        done
else
        for counter in "${VALARR[@]}"
        do
                dostuff $counter
        done
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree with the previous comments that 2 `for` loops is not as offensive as it may look.

Second, you can't conditionally kick off a `for` loop in the manner of your example.  But, you can manipulate your array with a conditional.

So to satisfy your question, here would be a simple solution:

```
FROMVAL=1
TOVAL=5
VALARR=(1 3 5)
ISCONSEQ=0

if (( ISCONSEQ != 1))
then
    VALARR=($(seq $FROMVAL 1 $TOVAL))
fi

for counter in "${VALARR[@]}"
do
  echo "$counter"
done
```

Comment: The "simple" solution looks very much like the last sample in the question - what did you change there?

Comment: Gah!  I didn't see it.  Please disregard.

Comment: I added the last sample after original posting. Could be that. The question was out of curiosity, given that Bash bends in almost any direction, while, for readability's sake, the function implementation is way better. Thank you for this input as well.